# jQuery width does not include inner element padding

Tags: javascript, html, css

When an element contains inline-blocks which contain padding it doesn't get included in the width calculations of the element.

Essentially the same issue as [jQuery outerWidth on a parent element which has child elements with padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194138/jquery-outerwidth-on-a-parent-element-which-has-child-elements-with-padding).

This page should have text that lines up along the right side of the green box,
however the text will always grow larger than it's container, because width never includes the padding of any of it's children.

Is there a way to find the width of an element correctly without manually enumerating all child elements and re-adding the padding of each child?  Same results when using `.css('width')`, `.width()` or `.outerWidth()`.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var e = jQuery('#BLAH');
      var pw = e.parent().width();
      e.css('font-size','1px');
      if (e.outerWidth() < pw) {
        while ( e.outerWidth() < pw) {
          alert('width ' + e.outerWidth() + ' < ' + pw);
          e.css('font-size','+=1px');
        }
        e.css('font-size','-=1px');
      }
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #BLAH {
      background-color: red;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .BLAH {
      //padding: 0 10%;
      background-color: blue;
      display: inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: green; width: 50%; height: 50%">
      <div id="BLAH" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="BLAH">BLAH</div>
        <div class="BLAH">BLAH</div>
        <div class="BLAH">BLAH</div>
        <div class="BLAH">BLAH</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at [`box-sizing:border-box`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: The issue seems specific to percentage based padding.  I assume the issue is that if the percentage padding were factored in, it would be an infinite loop to try and calculate widths.  The padding affects the width, but the width affects the padding.

Comment: not an infinite loop: parentWidth=totalChildFixedWidths/(1-totalChildPercentPadding), but instead of doing what is obvious the W3C decided to declare that common sense is in fact undefined behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the issue only occurs with percentage padding, you can instead use fixed pixel padding and increase that along with your font-size in the javascript.  Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var e = jQuery('#BLAH');
    var pw = e.parent().width();
    e.css('font-size', '1px');
    if (e.outerWidth() < pw) {
        while (e.outerWidth() < pw) {
            console.log('width ' + e.outerWidth() + ' < ' + pw);
            e.css('font-size', '+=1px');

            jQuery(".BLAH").css({
                'padding-right': '+=1px',
                'padding-left': '+=1px'
            });
        }

        e.css('font-size', '-=1px');

        jQuery(".BLAH").css({
            'padding-right': '-=1px',
            'padding-left': '-=1px'
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Gufk/

If you wanted to get more sophisticated with it, you could calculate the padding as a percentage of the parent element's previous width and apply that rather than just increasing by one, or any other formula.

---

As for why it works this way, I was unable to find the part of the CSS spec that defines this behavior.  However, it is important to understand that a percentage padding is based on the width of the containing block.  Consider how it would work if you had 6 elements, all with 10% padding on both sides.  That would be 120% padding, how could that even be possible for the padding of the elements to be 120% of the width of the parent element and still fit inside the parent?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties "If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1"

Comment: As soon as I saw the first comment about 'infinite loop' I remembered that I made this mistake back in 2004, around the time I started going to college, and it was like a year latter that I gave up on html+css+javaScript as a joke, these days it has gotten better, but alas it's still an absurd joke.